# can't connect to wifi network with Odroid c0 with minimal Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu-minimal, wpa-supplicant

I want to connect to a wifi where a /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf is suggested:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
ap_scan=1

network={
   ssid="####"
   proto=RSN
   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
   pairwise=TKIP
   auth_alg=OPEN
   eap=PEAP
   identity="####"
   password="####"
   ca_cert="/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.org.pem"
   phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

I already commented proto and key_mgmt because I couldn't find the problem

so here is the relevant part of my iwconfig:

```
wlx7cdd90ae2375  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

and here is the ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:06:20:43:40  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:6ff:fe20:4340/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:19278 (19.2 KB)
          Interrupt:40 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)

wlx7cdd90ae2375 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:dd:90:ae:23:75  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1017 (1.0 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

then I tried sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -d:

```
wpa_supplicant v2.4
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlx7cdd90ae2375' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' driver 'wext' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
ctrl_interface='/var/run/wpa_supplicant'
ctrl_interface_group='0'
ap_scan=1
Line 16: removed CCMP from group cipher list since it was not allowed for pairwise cipher
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='####'
WEXT: cfg80211-based driver detected
wext: interface wlx7cdd90ae2375 phy: phy0
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
SIOCGIWRANGE: WE(compiled)=22 WE(source)=21 enc_capa=0xf
  capabilities: key_mgmt 0xf enc 0x1f flags 0x0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=5 linkmode=1 (userspace-control), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
Add interface wlx7cdd90ae2375 to a new radio phy0
wlx7cdd90ae2375: Own MAC address: 7c:dd:90:ae:23:75
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_countermeasures
wlx7cdd90ae2375: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
wlx7cdd90ae2375: No enabled networks (1 disabled networks)
wlx7cdd90ae2375: State: DISCONNECTED -> INACTIVE
TDLS: TDLS operation not supported by driver
TDLS: Driver uses internal link setup
TDLS: Driver does not support TDLS channel switching
wlx7cdd90ae2375: WPS: UUID based on MAC address: d9d8434c-a009-5512-a2e0-281db564c0b2
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
ctrl_interface_group=0
wlx7cdd90ae2375: Added interface wlx7cdd90ae2375
wlx7cdd90ae2375: State: INACTIVE -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlx7cdd90ae2375' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b06 len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlx7cdd90ae2375' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlx7cdd90ae2375' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlx7cdd90ae2375' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlx7cdd90ae2375' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlx7cdd90ae2375' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
EAPOL: disable timer tick
wlx7cdd90ae2375: Removing interface wlx7cdd90ae2375
wlx7cdd90ae2375: Request to deauthenticate - bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 pending_bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3 state=DISCONNECTED
TDLS: Tear down peers
wlx7cdd90ae2375: State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_countermeasures
wlx7cdd90ae2375: WPA: Clear old PMK and PTK
wlx7cdd90ae2375: Cancelling scan request
wlx7cdd90ae2375: Cancelling authentication timeout
Remove interface wlx7cdd90ae2375 from radio phy0
Remove radio phy0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=5 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
wlx7cdd90ae2375: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

well it's my first time working with an os without gui and I still work with a hdmi connected display, because I can't manage to install anything since I have no internet. If you need any further information, just tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this official wiki page:

http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:minimal_image_wifi_setup

I confirm that the instructions worked for me just now on an ODROID C1+ running the official ODROID minimal Ubuntu 16.04 image.

I did have a problem because I am using the infamous Edimax 7811UN USB WiFi dongle. It requires two extra steps:

1) I had to add -D wext to the end of the wpa_supplicant line in the .service file per the last post in this thread:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=104856

2) And the other step is the infamous Edimax power save problem.

If you have a WiFi adapter with the same chipset, you'll probably need to troubleshoot/fix it.

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot about this question
I actually don't even have the odroid anymore, my boss switched to raspi :/ so I cannot even try it anymore